# Applying AJAX to refresh contents of a table designed in HTML and Perl

Tags: html, ajax, perl

I am having issue in applying AJAX so as to refresh certain contents of a table designed in HTML and Perl.

Say, if the contents of the following cells
***{R2,C3},{R3,C4},{R4,C(5-7)}, {R(7-10),C(8-11)}***
need to be refreshed every 10 seconds,
what shall be the corresponding **PERL** code for the same?

Millie a Thanks for sharing your Kowledge and Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the data you want (how you do this depends on how it is stored).
2. Convert it to JSON (the [`JSON` module](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) is well documented) … assuming you want to use JSON, although it is a common choice.
3. Output a `Content-Type: application/json` header (how you do this depends on the method by which you are interacting with your web server, it will be different between Plack / a framework / mod_perl / raw CGI / etc) … the same assumption applies.
4. Output the JSON text (ditto).

There is a [simple example using FastCGI](https://github.com/dorward/simple-ajax-demo/blob/master/webroot/demo.pl).

Comment: Thanks Quentin for looking into the issue. 

1. The data is being retrieved from a URL. Perl is being used to extract the data.
2. It would be better if the formats remain in Perl and HTML only.

Comment: If you mean "The data is being retrieved from a URL by JavaScript" then that is what Ajax means. The Perl that responds to the HTTP request can't conjure it up from thin air though. If you mean "The data is being retrieved from a URL by Perl" then get it by whatever means you usually would. LWP is the usual tool of choice.

Comment: You can send HTML back if you want.

Comment: But i suppose there has to be some coding done in the Perl script so as to do the same.

Comment: To do the same as what? To send back HTML? Yes, you just need to convert the raw data to HTML instead of to JSON. That's no different from any other time you would want to generate HTML from Perl. The example code I linked to even does that if the request isn't marked as being for the Ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to build a JS method to Asynchronously obtain content from server side
2. You need a server side module (pearl in this case) to produce that content, there is no special code requiered on the same . you can use your existing PERL server-side module.

Comment: Thanks TechExchange for looking into the matter.

1. The contents of the table are stored in a URL, from where they are being extracted and hence being stored in a table.

What shall be the code for repetitively extracting the data and refreshing the same?